# Getting "RuntimeException: Unknown column {} during deserialization" after adding a column to a table

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-4.0

I tried to add a text column to a Cassandra table and a few requests failed in my java application during the alter operation with the following error:

```
Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_QUORUM \
  (3 responses were required but only 1 replica responded, 2 failed)
```

I have found this log in one of the nodes:

```
ERROR [Messaging-EventLoop-3-2] 2022-08-31 14:56:13,486 InboundMessageHandler.java:182 - unexpected exception caught while deserializing a message
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown column {} during deserialization
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Columns$Serializer.deserialize(Columns.java:463)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.ColumnFilter$Serializer.deserializeRegularAndStaticColumns(ColumnFilter.java:1072)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.ColumnFilter$Serializer.deserialize(ColumnFilter.java:1021)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadCommand$Serializer.deserialize(ReadCommand.java:928)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadCommand$Serializer.deserialize(ReadCommand.java:833)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.Message$Serializer.deserializePost40(Message.java:782)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.Message$Serializer.deserialize(Message.java:642)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.InboundMessageHandler.processSmallMessage(InboundMessageHandler.java:168)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.InboundMessageHandler.processOneContainedMessage(InboundMessageHandler.java:151)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.AbstractMessageHandler.processFrameOfContainedMessages(AbstractMessageHandler.java:242)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.AbstractMessageHandler.processIntactFrame(AbstractMessageHandler.java:227)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.AbstractMessageHandler.process(AbstractMessageHandler.java:218)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.FrameDecoder.deliver(FrameDecoder.java:321)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.FrameDecoder.channelRead(FrameDecoder.java:285)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.FrameDecoder.channelRead(FrameDecoder.java:269)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    ...
```

But I also have found this log in another node:

```
DEBUG [Native-Transport-Requests-3] 2022-08-31 14:56:12,900 ReadCallback.java:119 - Failed; received 1 of 3 responses (only digests)
DEBUG [Native-Transport-Requests-2] 2022-08-31 14:56:13,486 ReadCallback.java:119 - Failed; received 1 of 3 responses (only digests)
DEBUG [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2022-08-31 14:56:14,149 ReadCallback.java:119 - Failed; received 1 of 3 responses (including data)
```

I'm using cassandra 4.0.4 with java driver: 4.14.1.

I was hoping that the add column operation would not cause errors in the queries.
Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't so much that you updated the table definition. The real issue is that your nodes are unresponsive leading to errors like:

```
... (3 responses were required but only 1 replica responded, 2 failed)
```

and:

```
... Failed; received 1 of 3 responses (only digests)
```

When you perform schema changes and nodes are unresponsive, the schema change will not get propagated to those nodes. That's the reason you're getting read errors with "Unknown column" -- it's a schema disagreement.

You need to address the underlying issue which is nodes are unresponsive. In my experience, the most likely cause is that your cluster is overloaded so you need to increase the capacity to cope with the load.

As a side note, your keyspace must have a replication factor of 5 for `LOCAL_QUORUM` to require 3 replicas to respond to a read request. Is that intentional? For almost all cases, a replication factor of 3 in each DC is recommended and sufficient.

When I see `RF:5` I immediately think maybe it is a mistake and the operator didn't understand the implication. But if you have a specific requirement to have 5 replicas then that's fine as long as you know what you're doing. Cheers!

Comment: I have RF:5 with 5 nodes, and that's intentional.
Do you think this could be the problem?

I don't have reasons to think that the cluster is overloaded...